iOS Video player supporting frame by frame and forward and reverse playback
I've had a search around the App Store but not had much success so far.
I'm looking for a video player that can play local video files to help me review incidents looking at in-car footage downloaded from the competitors in-car systems (mostly mp4).
I need to be able to play forward and reverse, at speeds from from frame-by-frame to 2x (ideally controlled via intuitive on screen controls or a jog dial).
I suspect my answer is going to be a NLE (eg LumaFusion) but was hoping for something lighter touch
